# can i use django to access folders on my pc using same os.path for windows?

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I have a python algorithm that access a huge database in my laptop. I want to create a web server to work with it. can I use django with the folder paths I have used ? like how do I communicate with it ? I want to get an image from web application and get it sent to my laptop and run algorithm on it then send result back to the webserver. would that still be possible without me changing my algorithm paths? like I use os.path to access my database folder, would I still be able to do what with django or shall I learn something else? I wanted to try django as it runs in python and I can learn it easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that django works fine with os.path and no problems. actually if you are programming with python then django is a great choice for server work.